# PHP Uploading Script: Error 7

Tags: php, .htaccess, file-upload, upload

I'm working on a website, and I need help on one of the scripts that I am using to upload files.
I have a PHP script that allows the user to select a file to be uploaded, and for small files, it seems to work.
However, if the user tries to upload a bigger file, ~3MB, the script won't upload the file, and it will end up with Upload Error 7, which is UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE: Failed to write file to disk.

I'll attach the scripts here for you to look at.

Here is the HTML form:

```
<form action="uploader.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select file to upload:<br /><br />
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</form>
```

Here is the PHP script I use for uploading - uploader.php:
Some info about it:
I get the extension of the file uploaded, and create a folder with the name of the extension, and put the file inside. The directory I store the files in is one folder back, in the files folder.
I've seen other people's posts where they suggested trying to change PHP vars like post_max_size, and I have changed them all accordingly - but the script still does not work. I really need help.

```
<?php
//Upload Folder
$dir = "../files/";

//Uploaded File
$target_file = $dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
//File's Extension
$extension = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
//Filename
$filename = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_BASENAME);

//The folder that is created for the extension
$location = "{$dir}/{$extension}";
//Where the file is placed in the extension folder
$filelocation = "{$location}/{$filename}";

//The fixed file name, with the location set for where it will be placed.
$target_file_2 = $dir . $extension . "/" . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

//Link executed after upload...
$link = "http://test.com";

//Debug: Array showing the file's upload status (where I see it hits the error 07)
print_r($_FILES["fileToUpload"]);

//If extension folder exists/doesn't exist
if(file_exists($location))
{
        //Uploads the uploaded file, and moves it to the target location: ../files/EXTENSION/filename
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file_2);
    //header("Location: $link");
}
else
{
        //Creates the Extension folder if it does not exist.
    mkdir($location);
        //Uploads the uploaded file, and moves it to the target location: ../files/EXTENSION/filename
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file_2);
    //header("Location: $link");
}
?>
```

When I try to upload files that are smaller, it is successful, and the debug print shows something like this:

```
Array ( [name] => README.txt [type] => text/plain [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpCWbyT5 [error] => 0 [size] => 366 )
```

It successfully uploads with 0 errors.
However, if I try to upload a bigger file...

```
Array ( [name] => testupload.file [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 7 [size] => 0 )
```

It shows that the error I get from uploading is 7, and the size is 0.
I've already tried the fixes such as adding "php_value post_max_size 50M" or other fixes to my .htaccess file, nothing seems to work. I can verify that the changes take place, but it still doesn't fix the upload.
If anyone knows what to do, any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Edit: I don't think it's an error with the PHP script, as I've tried other people's 'working' upload scripts and it never seems to work for me for bigger files. Anyone have any idea?